# Rails: Restrict Nested Resource Path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-routing, nested-resources

I'd like to keep my nested resources within the context of its parent. Here's my code below:

*routes.rb* :

```
resources :categories do
  resources :subcategories
end
```

*migration* :

```
create_table "categories" do |t|
  t.string "name"
end

create_table "subcategories" do |t|
  t.string  "name"
  t.integer "category_id"
end
```

*models* :

```
class Categories < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :subcategories
end

class Subcategories < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
end
```

Here's my data:
`Category` `id`: [1, 2]
`Subcategory` `id`: [1..10], `category_id`: 1
`Subcategory` `id`: [11..20], `category_id`: 2

For my paths, *`/category/1/subcategory/[1..10]`* works perfectly fine. However, if I edit the url directly to *`/category/1/subcategory/[11..20]`*, the subcategories still show even though they are under `category id: 2`.

I must be missing something in my code. Something tells me that's not how it's supposed to work. It should throw an error if you're entering in a `subcategory` `id` that isn't associated to its `category_id`.

How would I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I don't see the controller method I suppose that the search is running only with one parameter (instead of necessary two), `params[:id]` (which is the `id` of the `subcategory`). As a result, you always get the `subcategory` with the provided `id`, but not within some (*also provided*) `category` `id`. You can do something like this to solve the issue you're struggling with :

```
@data = Category.find(params[:category_id])
                .subcategories
                .find(params[:id])
```

Comment: I'll have the try that. But even then, I'm not sure this fixes the problem of editing the url directly, does it?

Comment: @leejay100: As a matter of fact, it does. You can imagine it as a chain of checks: let's say, the uri is  `/category/1/subcategory/15`. So, at first, the method finds all categories with `id = 1` (as you can see, you have only one). Then it finds all it's `subcategories` (`[1..10]`), then it tries to find the subcategory with the  `id = 15` within this collection, but there is none of it, hence there is nothing to display.

Comment: Ah, I see. I would just put this in the show method. Thanks @notulysses